# If there is incliment weather on Yom Kippor may one wear leather shoes to the synogogue?

Tags: yom-kippur, weather, leniencies, inuy-affliction

In the event of inclement weather on Yom Kippur, may one wear leather shoes (which are the only inclement-weather-proof shoes available) to synagogue? I am asking about walking there in the morning, say, and then changing shoes to non-leather shoes once one has arrived at the synagogue.

Comment: I once had this issue on Tisha b'Av. I only had leather shoes so I took them off before entering schul. Also had this problem last night where I didn't have time to change shoes before davening so I kicked them off for tefillot.

Comment: I had heard that soldiers in the IDF wear leather boots on Yom Kippur, but only when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן קלג - הלכות יום הכפורים](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0132_L2) says:

> **סעיף ח'** 
>   נְעִילַת הַסַּנְדָּל, יֵשׁ אוֹסְרִין אֲפִלּוּ בְּסַנְדָּל שֶל עֵץ שֶׁאֵינוֹ חָפוּי בְּעוֹר. אֲבָל שֶׁל גֶּמִי אוֹ קַשׁ אוֹ בֶגֶד, מֻתָּר. **וְיֵשׁ לְהַחְמִיר בִּנְעִילַת הַסַּנְדָּל אֲפִלוּ בִּמְקוֹם רֶפֶשׁ וְטִיט וּגְשָׁמִים**. וַאֲפִלּוּ הוֹלֵךְ בֵּין הַגּוֹיִם, אָסוּר. **וְאִם הוּא מִצְטַעֵר הַרְבֵּה לֵילֵךְ בִּמְקוֹם רֶפֶשׁ וְטִיט וּגְשָׁמִים בְּלִי סַנְדָּל, יִנְעֹל סַנְדָּלִים שֶׁהֵם בְּלִי עָקֵב, אוֹ מִנְעָלִים שֶׁהֵם עִם עָקֵב אֶלָּא יַחֲלִיפֵם שֶׁל שְׂמֹאל לְיָמִין וְשֶׁל יָמִין לִשְׂמֹאל אִם יֵשׁ חִלּוּק בֵּינֵיהֶם, וְלִפְנֵי פֶתַח בֵּית הַכְּנֶסֶת יַחֲלֹץ אוֹתָם וְיַצְנִיעֵם.** וְיִזָּהֵר שֶׁלֹּא לִגַּע בָּהֶם לֹא בִנְעִילָה וְלֹא בַחֲלִיצָה, שֶׁלֹּא יִצְטָרֵךְ לִרְחוֹץ יָדָיו. ‏

One should not wear leather shoes even if it means walking through mud or rain.

However, if doing so would cause major distress, then one should wear shoes without a sole. Alternately one can switch the left and right shoes - if there's a difference between them - and at the entrance of the Shul one removes them and hides them.

If possible, one should not touch the shoes - when putting them on or removing them - so as not to have to wash one's hands.

The Remo in Shulchan Aruch [סימן תריד - דיני סיכה ונעילת הסנדל](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_35.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2) (last sentence) says:

> **הגה**: וְאִם יָרְדוּ  גְּשָׁמִים וְרוֹצֶה לֵילֵךְ לְבֵיתוֹ מִבֵּית הַכְּנֶסֶת אוֹ לְהֶפֶךְ, וְהוּא אִיסְטְנִיס, מֻתָּר לִנְעֹל מִנְעָלָיו עַד שֶׁמַּגִּיעַ לִמְקוֹמוֹ (מַהֲרִי''ל). ‏

If it's raining and one wants to go to/from shul, and one is *delicate* (i.e. unable to walk in the rain barefoot) then one may wear [leather] shoes until one reaches one's destination.

The [Kitzur Yalkut Yosef](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_29.html#HtmpReportNum0012_L2) also does not mention switching shoes, and adds that if the floor of the [public] bathroom is not clean, one may wear one's [leather] shoes to enter.

> ה אם ירדו גשמים, והרחוב עמוס רפש וטיט, ורוצה לצאת לבית הכנסת, מותר לו לנעול נעליו ולצאת בהם לרשות הרבים, ומיד כשיגיע לבית הכנסת יחלוץ אותם. וכן **אם רוצה להכנס לבית הכסא, והרצפה לא נקיה, מותר לנעול נעליו עד שיצא מבית הכסא**. [כ''כ בשיורי כנה''ג (הגה''ט ר''ס תריד), וכמ''ש כיו''ב הרמ''א בהגה, שאם ירדו גשמים מותר לנעול מנעליו עד שיגיע למקומו].‏